# Make Teradata Sql Assistant default to vertical tabs

Tags: teradata

Is there a way to make Teradata Sql Assistant default to vertical columns?  I can manually set my results in a vertical tab, but when I execute the query again it puts them right back at the bottom in a horizontal tab.

I tried untabbed, and placed the windows where I wanted them, and when I execute a query it sticks the results behind the query window and shrinks the results window!

This is driving me absolutely insane... Is there any way to just make the results return in a default vertical window so I can see them and my query side by side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
Window -> Tabbed
Window -> New Vertical Table Group
```

SQLA 14.10.0.5, what's your release?

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying, it just reverts to the bottom when I execute the query... I'm in 13.0.0.13 though.

Comment: Upgraded and it works beautifully.  Thanks so much.  This was making me lose my mind.